# Необходимо передать значения из формы в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql

На сайте есть форма, мне нужно передать информацию из нее в базу данных. После нажатия кнопки происходит обновление страницы, в базу ничего не попадает

Уже проверял запрос в базе, он все правильно забивает как надо

Такой вот код получился

```
include("dbinfo.php");


if (!mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password)) 
     {echo "ошибка подключения!"; exit;}

   mysql_set_charset("CP1251");
   mysql_select_db($database) or die ("Невозможно открыть $database");

$id = $_POST['id'];
$kod = $_POST['kod'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$count = $_POST['count'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

if(isset($submit)){
    if(isset($id) && isset($kod) && isset($price) && isset($count) && isset($type) && isset($name)){
        $query = "INSERT INTO `myBase`(`orderNum`, `kodProd`, `priceProd`, `countProd`, `typeProd`, `nameProd`) VALUES ('{$id}', '{$kod}', '{$price}', '{$count}', '{$type}', '{$name}')";
        if(mysql_query($database, $query)){
            echo "Запись добавлена!";
        }

    }
}

echo("<form method=\"POST\">
    <input type=\"text\" name=\"id\" id=\"1\" value=\"\" class=\"kdHolder\" >
    <input type=\"text\" name=\"kod\" id=\"2\" value=\"\" class=\"kdHolder\">
    <input type=\"text\" name=\"price\" id=\"3\" value=\"\" class=\"kdHolder\">
    <input type=\"text\" name=\"count\" id=\"4\" value=\"\" class=\"kdHolder\">
    <input type=\"text\" name=\"type\" id=\"5\" value=\"\" class=\"kdHolder\">
    <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" id=\"6\" value=\"\" class=\"kdHolder\">
    <input type=\"submit\" name=\"button_id\" value=\"Ввести данные\" class=\"sendBtn\">
</form>");

mysql_close();
```

Comment: `echo $query` - и попробуйте выполнить этот запрос в консольном клиенте. PS. Думаю, фигурные скобки там не по делу... а вообще возьмите за правило не игнорировать ошибки и выводить сообщения о них.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работайте правильно.Не используйте mysql (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php) оно уже устарело . Используйте mysqli или лучше сразу PDO

Comment: Не пользовался mysqli. Можно без особых временных затрат перейти?

Comment: mysqli идентично. PDO конечно посложнее

Comment: То есть я просто могу поменять везде, где написано mysql и на mysqli и все?

Comment: Погуглил чутка. И вот подключаюсь вот так `include("dbinfo.php");
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", $username, $password, $database); ` А  запрос выглядит таким образом `if(isset($submit)){
  if(isset($id) && isset($kod) && isset($price) && isset($count) && isset($type) && isset($name)){
  echo $query = "INSERT INTO `myBase`(`orderNum`, `kodProd`, `priceProd`, `countProd`, `typeProd`, `nameProd`) VALUES ('{$id}', '{$kod}', '{$price}', '{$count}', '{$type}', '{$name}')";
   if(mysqli_query($database, $query)){
    echo "Запись добавлена!";
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: Нет конечно. Кидаю ссылку на отличия(https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) там есть русский язык. Придется немного разобраться. Просто изучение mysql это путь в никуда.

Comment: Нашел простой пример https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/mysqli_insert_query.htm

Comment: Все получилось. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Дело наверно в том что имя кнопки у вас `button_id` а получаете вы:

`$submit = $_POST['submit'];`

Надо получать: `$submit = $_POST['button_id'];`,

Либо переименуйте `name="submit"` - в форме

Comment: Переделал на `$submit = $_POST['button_id'];`И теперь он выплевывает весь этот запрос мне на страницу. В базе так же ничего

Comment: вообще да еще одна из возможных  причин описана ниже